# How to get a HTML element by searching the content of innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

How to get a HTML element by searching the content of innerHTML?

For example, Search

I want to get the "a" tag by searching word "Search" using javascript.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var aTags = document.querySelectorAll('a');    
var searchaTag = '';
    for(i = 0; i<aTags.length; i++ ) {
    if(aTags[i].text == 'Search') {
     searchaTag = aTags[i];
     break;
    }

    }
```

Comment: but need to rename the linkTags var

Comment: @user3251954 Done! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you have no idea where the element can be, iterate over each element:

```
var all = document.querySelectorAll('*'); //OR document.getElementsByTagName("*")
for(var i = 0; i < all.length; i++ ) {
    if(all[i].innerHTML === "search") {
        console.log(all[i].tagName);
    }
}
```

If you have some clue you can narrow your search by looking inside that area:

```
var all = document.querySelector('#my-Container').getElementsByTagName('*');
```